# Super Attribute Pricing Report

Tags: magento-1.7, sql, pricing, superattribute

I need to update the prices of my simple products so that they appear properly in my Google Shopping data feed. A systematic/automatic approach is likely overkill since we only currently have about 60 products of almost 3000 with super attribute pricing. Ideally I would generate a report that lists which items are affected, and I can update their prices manually.

I've located the database table with the values (catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing), but I'm unclear on how to reference those values to the actual products that are affected.

1. How would I reference the catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing table values to actual products?
2. Is there a better way of figuring out which items are affected by super attribute pricing that I'm completely missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While clicking around before submitting my question, I found a potential solution:

I'm accessing my dB with Sequel Pro. When viewing the catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing table, there is a column labelled product_super_attribute_id. For each value of that column, there's an arrow that when clicked will take you to the catalog_super_attribute table. Within that table is a column labelled product_id, and clicking the arrow beside the relevant value will take you to the catalog_product_entity table, revealing the product SKU, thus making it simple to update the simple product pricing manually.